# Conditional Logic with floats not evaluating correctly

Tags: java, android, if-statement, floating-point, rectangles

I have the following code and despite numerous attempts to get it to evaluate properly, I can't get it to work. I have a work around to check each item individually (in which case it works) but the fact that I can write what appears to be a simple math statement and it doesn't work is troubling.

I've checked the values of the points and they are well within the rectangle it will return false. If I check each individually, it will evaluate them properly and I get a true value.

Thanks in advance for your time!

```
public static boolean checkIfPointInRectangle(RectF rect, float canvasRotateAngle, float objRotationAngle, int sketchPadHeight, int sketchPadWidth, float pointX, float pointY) {
    float[] points = new float[] { pointX, pointY };

    // Transform the points to the current rotation
    Matrix transform = new Matrix();        
    transform.setRotate(objRotationAngle - canvasRotateAngle, sketchPadWidth / 2, sketchPadHeight / 2);
    transform.mapPoints(points);

    if(((rect.left <= points[0]) && (points[0] < rect.right) && (rect.top <= points[1]) && (points[1] < rect.bottom))){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand properly. The if statement should resolve to true, if the point is inside the rectangle? If so, the `rect.top` is the upper bound and should be `>` pointY?

Comment: What happens if you say: `if (rect.contains(points[0], points[1])) { ...` ?